# Padding bottom hack not working when image scales down within container

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, reflow

I've implemented the padding bottom hack by covering ALL aspect ratios ie `padding-bottom: calc(~'var(--imageHeight) / var(--imageWidth) * 100%');`

This works great on desktop and on most images on mobile. The images though won't always be filling 100% of the container. So i have a situation where the say X amount of padding is added to the container but on mobile, the portrait image is scaling down within the container causing a space above/below. See image [image: here]

Does anyone have any advice on how to overcome this?